# Why does my takeUntil using a subject and auth service not work?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, rxjs

In my firebase angular app i have to manage a lot of subscriptions. Thats why i created a `AngularLifecycle.helper.ts` class to help me, unsubscribe from observables like this:

AngularLifecycle.helper.ts:

```
export class AngularLifecycle implements OnDestroy {
  private destroySubject = new Subject();

  public get destroyed$() {
    return this.destroySubject.asObservable();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.destroySubject.next();
    this.destroySubject.complete();
  }
}
```

in any class where i subscribe to observables, i extend from the AngularLifecycle class and unsubscribe like that:

```
this.afAuth.authState.pipe(
  takeUntil(this.destroyed$)
  ...
```

However i subscribe to observables in my app.component.ts and when the user logs out i get a permission denied error from firebase, because there are still some subscriptions going on.

```
ERROR FirebaseError: 
false for 'list' @ L42
    at new n (prebuilt-e10b3b00-01f089b3.js:188)
    at prebuilt-e10b3b00-01f089b3.js:10425
    at prebuilt-e10b3b00-01f089b3.js:10423
    at n.onMessage (prebuilt-e10b3b00-01f089b3.js:10412)
    at prebuilt-e10b3b00-01f089b3.js:10365
    at prebuilt-e10b3b00-01f089b3.js:10396
    at prebuilt-e10b3b00-01f089b3.js:15145
    at prebuilt-e10b3b00-01f089b3.js:15203
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:372)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.js:28705)
```

I knew, app.component wasn't destroyed on logout, so i tried to stop them with a custom `loggedOut$` subject in my auth service like this:

Auth Service

```
export class AuthService extends AngularLifecycle {
  private loggedOut$ = new Subject();

  constructor (private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {}

  getLoggedOut$() {
    return this.loggedOut$.asObservable();
  }

  signOut() {
    this.afAuth.signOut();
    this.loggedOut$.next();
    this.loggedOut$.complete();
  }
}
```

app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent extends AngularLifecycle {
  private unsubscribe$ = new Subject<void>();

  constructor(private groupDataService: GroupDataService,
              public authService: AuthService) {
    this.authService.getLoggedOut$()
      .pipe(
        takeUntil(this.destroyed$)
      ).subscribe((res) => {
        this.unsubscribe$.next();
        this.unsubscribe$.complete();
    });

    this.groupDataService.getActiveGroup$()
      .pipe(
        takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)
      ).subscribe(group => {
        this.group = group;
    });
  }
}
```

But when the user logs out the same error appears. The `loggedOut$` subject of the auth service fires for sure, but i don't know, why the takeUntil does not stop the subscription.

Comment: `takeUntil(this.destroyed$)` ? Isn't `destroyed$` a function and not an observable? `takeUntil` requires an observable.

Comment: I guess not, because i extend the class in order to use it, and this part also works fine in my app

Comment: Ah, I see, I don't use JS classes much and forgot about getter and setter methods. Fair enough

Comment: Which `subscription` do you need exactly to `unsubscribe` on destroy?